# where to place while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, file-io

I have this program which processes the orders of a user asking for different cupcakes. The issue I'm having is that once the user inputs 0 (indicating that they want their order to be completed), the program is immediately supposed keep running after the user entered 0, and to make it go to the next order (#0002) with 0 money to be paid whilst simultaneously decreasing the amount of cupcakes remaining by the amount that the previous user ordered. This is what the output is supposed to look like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sckw.png)
All the way until the cupcakes run out, in which the output looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHH9b.png)
The Issue I'm having is that my program immediately stops after I complete the first order, and does not take any more user input. I know that I'm supposed to use a while loop, which is using the "stock" boolean to control it, but I'm not sure where to place it.
Here's my code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

        public class TheCupcakeFactory 
        {
            private static Scanner inputFile;
            /*
             *Diego Molina Salinas
             *CS160 Fall 2023
             *Project 4: The Cupcake Factory Sales
             *
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
            {
                Cupcake cupcakeCS = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeAP = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeBF = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeBS = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeBW = new Cupcake();
                int quantity = 0;
                int orderNum = 0;
                boolean stock = true;
                Cupcake [] cupcakes = {cupcakeCS, cupcakeAP, cupcakeBF, cupcakeBS, cupcakeBW};
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Cupcake Factory Sales Registry!!");

                
                    FileReader file = new FileReader("FreshCupcakes.txt");
                    inputFile = new Scanner(file);
//                  while(stock) {
                    orderNum++;
                    printMenu(cupcakeCS, "Moist chocolate cake filled with strawberry jam, topped with strawberry buttercream dipped in chocolate.", 2.75);
                    printMenu(cupcakeAP, "Moist vanilla cake filled with apple pie filling; topped with cream cheese icing, apple pie filling, and cinnamon streusel", 3.25);
                    printMenu(cupcakeBF, "Moist chocolate cake filled and topped with our peanut butter icing and Butterfinger candy.", 2.95);
                    printMenu(cupcakeBS, "Moist chocolate cake filled with banana filling, topped with our vanilla buttercream with sprinkles, cherry and chocolate drizzle on top.", 3.15);
                    printMenu(cupcakeBW, "Moist vanilla cupcake, topped with our rich fudge icing", 3.50);
//                  if(cupcakeCS.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeAP.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeBF.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeBS.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeBW.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 )
//                  {
//                      System.out.println("We are sorry, our yummy cupcakes are sold out.");
//                      stock = false;
//                      break;
//                  }
//                  }
                    for (int i = 0; i < cupcakes.length; i++) 
                    {
                        System.out.println((i + 1) + ".) " + cupcakes[i]);
                    }
                    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                    boolean loopRunner = true;
                    int [] quantities = new int[cupcakes.length];
                    while (loopRunner) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please enter your choice (0 if done): ");
                        int choice = kb.nextInt();

                        if (choice == 0 ) 
                        {
                            printReceipt(cupcakes, quantities, orderNum);
                            break;
                        }

//                      if(cupcakeCS.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeAP.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeBF.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeBS.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 && cupcakeBW.getUnitsOnHand() == 0 )
//                      {
//                          System.out.println("We are sorry, our yummy cupcakes are sold out.");
//                          loopRunner = false;
//                          break;
//                      }
                        if (choice < 1 || choice > cupcakes.length) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice. Pick again.");
                            continue;
                        }
                         quantity = 0;
                        boolean validQuantity = false;
                        while(!validQuantity)
                        {
                        System.out.println("How many pieces? ");
                        quantity = kb.nextInt();

                        if (quantity <= cupcakes[choice - 1].getUnitsOnHand()) 
                        {
                            validQuantity = true;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Not enough units available for that cupcake.");
                        }
                        }
                        quantities[choice - 1] = quantity;
                        double totalCost = costTotal(cupcakes[choice - 1].getPrice(), quantity);
                        System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + totalCost);
                        cupcakes[choice - 1].setUnitsOnHand(cupcakes[choice - 1].getUnitsOnHand() - quantity);

                        
            }
                    printReceipt(cupcakes, quantities, orderNum);

            }
            public static void printMenu(Cupcake cupcake, String description, double price) 
            {
                cupcake.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
                cupcake.setDescription(description);
                cupcake.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
                cupcake.setPrice(price);
            }
             public static double costTotal(double price, int quantity) 
             {
                    return price * quantity;
             }
             public static void getTax(double grandTotal)
                {
                    double totalWithTax = grandTotal *1.07;
                    System.out.println("Here's your total (Including Tax:) " + totalWithTax);
                }
             public static void printReceipt(Cupcake[] cupcakes, int [] quantities, int orderNum) 
             {
                 
                    System.out.println("Order #000" + orderNum);

                    double grandTotal = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
                        if(quantities[i] > 0)
                        {
                            double cupcakeTotal = quantities[i] * cupcakes[i].getPrice();
                            System.out.printf("%-25s $%.2f\n", cupcakes[i].getFlavor(), cupcakeTotal);
                            grandTotal +=cupcakeTotal;
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("\tTotal\t\t$" + grandTotal);
                    getTax(grandTotal);
             }
        }
```

As you can see, there are multiple lines in which I attempted to use the stock loop that are commented out. I left them there in case I was onto something so you guys could let me know how to fix this.

Here's what my output looks like:

```
Welcome to the Cupcake Factory Sales Registry!!
1.) Chocolate-Strawberry:  $2.75 - 
Moist chocolate cake filled with strawberry jam, topped with strawberry buttercream dipped in chocolate.
2.) Apple-Pie:  $3.25 - 
Moist vanilla cake filled with apple pie filling; topped with cream cheese icing, apple pie filling, and cinnamon streusel
3.) Butterfinger:  $2.95 - 
Moist chocolate cake filled and topped with our peanut butter icing and Butterfinger candy.
4.) Banana-Split:  $3.15 - 
Moist chocolate cake filled with banana filling, topped with our vanilla buttercream with sprinkles, cherry and chocolate drizzle on top.
5.) Black&White:  $3.5 - 
Moist vanilla cupcake, topped with our rich fudge icing
Please enter your choice (0 if done): 
3
How many pieces? 
2
Total Cost: $5.9
Please enter your choice (0 if done): 
0
Order #0001
Butterfinger              $5.90
    Total       $5.9
Here's your total (Including Tax:) 6.313000000000001
Order #0001
Butterfinger              $5.90
    Total       $5.9
Here's your total (Including Tax:) 6.313000000000001
```

and this is where the computer stops taking user input.

tried placing a while loop so that the program would keep running after the first order was entered, did not work that way, computer stopped taking inputs after first order where the user hits 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Given this is clearly course work of some description, I will offer some advice.  First of all break the problem down into small chunk, each chunk can be a method or a class.  Prefer `List` or other (appropriate) collections over arrays. Layout your code in a consistent way, a decent IDE such as IntelliJ can help with that.  Trying solving the issue of taking one order and ensuring the stock is correct before moving on to making the program take multiple orders.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes I would recommend you to do:

### Initialization first

You should initialize all the objects first.

Instead of printing `System.out.println("Welcome to the Cupcake Factory Sales Registry!!");` in between the declaration and initialization of your cupcakes do both first!

Best practice would be to define a function that reads the cupcake file and creates the cupcake array

This could look something like this:

```java
public static Cupcake[] createCupcakes(){
   Cupcake cupcakeCS = new Cupcake();
   Cupcake cupcakeAP = new Cupcake();
   Cupcake cupcakeBF = new Cupcake();
   Cupcake cupcakeBS = new Cupcake();
   Cupcake cupcakeBW = new Cupcake();
   int quantity = 0;
   int orderNum = 0;
   boolean stock = true;
   Cupcake [] cupcakes = {cupcakeCS, cupcakeAP, cupcakeBF, cupcakeBS, cupcakeBW};
   FileReader file = new FileReader("FreshCupcakes.txt");
   inputFile = new Scanner(file);
   printMenu(cupcakeCS, "Moist chocolate cake filled with strawberry jam, topped with strawberry buttercream dipped in chocolate.", 2.75);
   printMenu(cupcakeAP, "Moist vanilla cake filled with apple pie filling; topped with cream cheese icing, apple pie filling, and cinnamon streusel", 3.25);
   printMenu(cupcakeBF, "Moist chocolate cake filled and topped with our peanut butter icing and Butterfinger candy.", 2.95);
   printMenu(cupcakeBS, "Moist chocolate cake filled with banana filling, topped with our vanilla buttercream with sprinkles, cherry and chocolate drizzle on top.", 3.15);
   printMenu(cupcakeBW, "Moist vanilla cupcake, topped with our rich fudge icing", 3.50);
   return cupcakes;
}
```

This way you will create your cupcake array at a single point and won't get confused in the later process.

### Loop

Starting from `Welcome to the Cupcake Factory Sales Registry!!` to the output of the recipe everything should be repeated until there isn't a single cupcake left, right?
Considering this, where do you think you should put your loop?
Of course around all those outputs.

```java
public static void main(){
   Cupcake [] cupcakes = createCupcakes(); // use your cupcake function here to read the cupcake file only once
   while(stock){
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Cupcake Factory Sales Registry!!");
      // and your other working loop here as well
      if(...){
         stock = false // set stock to false if no cupcake is left
      }
   }
}
```

### Other stuff

If you want to improve your program even further make sure to change following:

#### Naming

Some of your function names seem a little misleading, f.e. `printMenu` isn't printing anything, instead it sets the values for the cupcake (setCupcakeValues).

#### Loops are your friend

Instead of creating 5 different variables for cupcakes, you could use a loop for creating them as well, if you do, I would also reconsider having an extra method just to set the values of the cupcake, rather than just doing it inside the loop.

#### Detach output from logic

generally functions like `getTax` shouldn't output anything, rather than returning the resulting value. Instead, you can just add it as parameter to `printReceipt` and print it there. But for your project this is not very relevant and doing it your way is also fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would have to look a bit like this:

```
while (have_stock) {
    Order order = getOrderInformation();
    processOrder(order);
}
```

Now what expressions you put inside the loop is quite flexible - I chose to put most of the logic into two different methods. You can do it differently if you prefer.
You should get there pretty fast since you sound like the application can process a single order already.